# jquery ui dropdown/select [rounded bottom]

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

Using this: http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/index.html

I'm using background images instead of gradients/plain colours.
I want to have the bottom of the dropdown box rounded,
this works:

```
.ui-corner-bottom {background:url(images/backbottom.png);}
```

but how do i access/call the selector which is made when you roll over the bottom?
this code gets called for hover on all the li.items,

```
 .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, 
 .ui-state-focus, 
 .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus {background:url(images/select.png) }
```

i assumed this would work but it doesnt

```
.ui-corner-bottom-hover {background:url(images/backbottom2.png); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
.ui-corner-bottom.ui-state-hover {
    background: url(images/backbottom2.png);
}
```

Jquery ui applies the ui-state-hover class to any element when it's hovered, by writing both classes together as the style will only be applied to elements that have both classes.

And some additional advice:
I recommend you to use css sprites for this hover effect, this way you avoid the ugly flash of nothing when hovering for the first time over an element that uses a different image for its hover state. Chris Coyier wrote up a nice summary/introduction here: http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-corner-bottom {background:url(images/backbottom2.png); }
```

but if you have an ID or something on the selectbox use it in your CSS, so it takes priority over the default JQUERY UI CSS file.

So something like

```
#mySelectbox .ui-corner-bottom {background:url(images/backbottom2.png); }
```

Comment: The tip with the id is great, but the question was about the hover state. Your answer will only style the button in it's normal state (which apparently already works if I understood the question right)